# Android TabLayout Inconsistent Tab Label Size

Tags: android, tabs

## Problem

To my understanding, the guidelines of material design mention that tab single-line labels should not be resized: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage

However, my tabLayout changes the size of a label and looks awful as seen in this picture:

[S6-TabMode-Fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29AmB.png)

**TabLayout Code:**

```
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.company_tabs);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    mTabLayout.setBackgroundColor(actionbarColor);
    mTabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE);
    mTabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.WHITE);
    mTabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
```

**TabLayout XML:**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/company_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

**Attempted:**

1. Changed tabmode to TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE, this resulted in tabs having the correct text size, but being left-aligned.
2. Experimented with favorites label, shortening the text to "favorit" seemed to fix the tab size from being resized, but this is not an acceptable solution

#### Question:

What is causing this behavior, and what can be done so that the tabs fit the full width of the screen, but the text size of the labels remains unchanged?

Comment: Noticed the same thing after updating to AppCompat 23.4.0, however downgrading again didn't fix!